# HDFS Data node not getting started with kerberos

Tags: authentication, hadoop, kerberos, hdfs

I have added kerberos authentication to apache hdfs, the namenode is up and running but I am not able to start datanode, getting this exception:

```
2012-08-23 17:05:45,648 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start secure cluster without privileged resources.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1665)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1682)
```

I am using apache hadoop version 1.0.1 on fedora 16 and not the cloudera version, jsvc file also exists under libexec.

Can someone please help me getting resolved this issue.

Thanks,
-Chhavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got through the exception, data node has to be started from the root in a secure cluster.